# How can I display the "from" address on received e-mails in Outlook?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

This *has* to be obvious, but how can I view the actual "from" address of a received e-mail?

[image]

Comment: double click on the face icon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### How can I display the “from” address on received e-mails in Outlook?

You can see the `from` email address in the full message headers.

---

#### Displaying Full Message Headers in Microsoft Outlook (Windows)

> **Outlook 2007/2010/2013**
>
> You can display full headers by double clicking on a message so that
>   it opens in a separate window (not the preview pane).
>
> 1. Start Outlook.
> 2. Double-click the message for which you want to view full internet headers.
> 3. Click Options (2007) or Tags (2010/2013).
>
> [image]
>
> The Message Options dialog box is displayed. The internet headers are
>   shown in the Internet headers field at the bottom of the dialog box.

You may have to scroll down to see the `from` address.

> [image]

Source [Displaying Full Message Headers in Microsoft Outlook (Windows)](http://its.yale.edu/how-to/email-and-calendars/yaleconnect/laptops-and-desktops/article-displaying-full-message-headers-microsoft-outlook-windows)

Comment: Thanks! I can't believe there's not a way to display it directly on the email window itself.